# What is the difference between "USB-C to HDMI Adapter" and "MHL"?

Tags: hdmi, video-streaming, mhl

When I search if Samsung Galaxy S8 supports MHL or not, I am getting crazy.

50% of online articles say S8 does not support MHL including [mhltech.org link](https://www.mhltech.org/devices.aspx?tid=1) and [technipages](https://www.technipages.com/connect-galaxy-s8-to-tv)

Another 50% of online articles say S8 supports MHL.

It obviously supports **USB-C to HDMI Adapter** which is only one side with Type-C port and another side with HDMI port cable.

If S8 does NOT support **MHL**, what is the difference between "USB-C to HDMI Adapter" and "MHL"?

Does "USB-C to HDMI Adapter" have worse video output than "MHL"?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: AFAIK MHL uses a passive cable, which means the used display has to support MHL. Where as HDMI is a common standard, so the converter is active: it has a chip which generates the HDMI signal from the signal it gets via USB (not sure what protocol is used on USB level).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that Samsung in all their infinite wisdom decided people needed a [DEX Station](https://www.samsung.com/uk/mobile-accessories/dex-station-mg950-ee-mg950bbegww/) to put their S8 into to achieve this purpose, to push their own devices/accessories instead of someone else's.